# Error al procesar thumbnail de imagen con PHP

Tags: php, gd

Estoy haciendo un buscador con ajax y funciona a la perfección, y en la tabla que muestra los resultados que se encuentran uno de ellos es una etiqueta para mostrar la imagen correspondiente a la fila del `id` seleccionado.

La imagen se guarda en una carpeta junto con su nombre, hasta ahí todo perfecto, mi código funciona y me di cuenta que cuando muestra la imagen del `id` tarda bastante en cargar ya que las imágenes se suben con un teléfono por lo que son de bastante calidad entonces decidí hacer una miniatura de la imagen con PHP para que no tardara tanto.

Y me funciona, osea doy click a la etiqueta y me muestra la miniatura bien, pero al momento que selecciono otra fila me muestra la miniatura de la fila anterior seleccionada hasta que le doy a actualizar (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

Estoy utilizando la biblioteca de funciones GD de PHP.

A continuación les dejo mi código PHP para mostrar la imagen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Mostrando Imagen</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
        include('conexion.php');
include 'config.inc.php';

$id = $_GET['Id'];

        $db=new Conect_MySql();
  $sql = "SELECT nombre_archivo, titulo FROM tabla_imagen_prueba WHERE Id = '$id'";
 $query = $db->execute($sql);
            while($datos=$db->fetch_row($query)){

                 $nombre_imagen = ("imagenes/{$datos['nombre_archivo']}");

        ?>



<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Mostrando foto del paciente: <?php echo $datos['titulo'] ?><a href="index.php" class="linkeador">     VOLVER</a></h1>

<img src="thumb_muestra100.jpg" >

</div>
<?php 

        function miniatura($archivo, $local, $ancho, $alto){    
            $arrNombre = explode(".", $local);
            $nombre = $arrNombre[0];
            $extension = $arrNombre[1];
            if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg") $nuevo = imagecreatefromjpeg($archivo);
            if($extension=="png") $nuevo = imagecreatefrompng($archivo);
            if($extension=="gif") $nuevo = imagecreatefromgif($archivo);
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho, $alto); // Lo haremos de un tamaño 100x100
            $ancho_original = imagesx($nuevo);
            $alto_original = imagesy($nuevo);
            imagecopyresampled($thumb,$nuevo,0,0,0,0,$ancho,$alto,$ancho_original,$alto_original);
            $thumb_name = "thumb_$nombre.$extension";
            if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg") imagejpeg($thumb, $thumb_name,70); // 90 es la calidad de compresión
            if($extension=="png") imagepng($thumb, $thumb_name);
            if($extension=="gif") imagegif($thumb, $thumb_name);
        }
        miniatura("$nombre_imagen", "muestra100.jpg", 650, 400);

        ?>


        <?php
            }
        ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estás guardando la miniatura siempre con el mismo nombre de archivo, por lo que podrías llegarse a dar el caso de ver la miniatura generada por otro usuario diferente. Deberías guardar las miniaturas en un directorio (para poder realizar una limpieza posterior de miniaturas antiguas que no se usan) y con el nombre de archivo basado en la clave primaria (para evitar duplicidad de miniaturas por compartir nombre de archivo).

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás guardando la miniatura siempre con el mismo nombre de archivo, por lo que podría llegarse a dar el caso de ver la miniatura generada por otro usuario diferente.

Deberías guardar las miniaturas en un directorio (para poder realizar una limpieza posterior de miniaturas antiguas que no se usan) y con el nombre de archivo basado en la clave primaria (para evitar duplicidad de miniaturas por compartir nombre de archivo).

Para empezar, cambiamos la imagen a mostrar de la siguiente manera:

```
<!-- Ojo que aquí estás forzando la extensión -->
<img src="miniaturas/<?= htmlspecialchars($id) ?>.jpg" />
```

Y posteriormente deberemos guardar la imagen de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Pasamos como parámetro el nombre (sin extensión) que debería tener */
miniatura($nombre_imagen, $i, 650, 400);
```

PD: En tu función no usas para nada el parámetro `$local`, terminas forzando el nombre de la miniatura. Deberías cambiarlo:

```
    function miniatura($archivo, $local, $ancho, $alto){    
        $arrNombre = explode(".", $archivo);
        $extension = $arrNombre[1];
        switch($extension) {
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
                $nuevo = imagecreatefromjpeg($archivo);
                break;
            case "png":
                $nuevo = imagecreatefrompng($archivo);
                break;
            case "gif":
                $nuevo = imagecreatefromgif($archivo);
        }
        // Lo haremos de un tamaño 100x100
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho, $alto);
        $ancho_original = imagesx($nuevo);
        $alto_original = imagesy($nuevo);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $nuevo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho, $alto, $ancho_original, $alto_original);
        $thumb_name = "miniaturas/$local.$extension";
        switch($extension) {
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
                // 70 es la calidad de compresión
                imagejpeg($thumb, $thumb_name, 70);
                break;
            case "png":
                imagepng($thumb, $thumb_name);
                break;
            case "gif":
                imagegif($thumb, $thumb_name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me funciono a la perfección. Muchas gracias

Comment: Y exelente la idea de asignar el id como nombre de la imagen

Comment: Gracias. Por norma general a las imágenes no se les deja con el nombre original o, si se hace, suele guardarse en un directorio o con un prefijo que esté asociado a su `id` o clave primaria para evitar duplicidad de archivos. Si no, un usuario malicioso podría subir una imagen con el mismo nombre que otra y sobreescribirla con, por ejemplo, una imagen de contenido de mal gusto. De paso aprovecho para avisarte que tú haces eso al almacenar la imagen en disco (en el directorio "imagenes") por lo que deberías pensar en solucionarlo.

Comment: Además, te recomiendo comprobar si la imagen en miniatura ya está generada previamente para no volver a generarla con, por ejemplo, [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists). Ahorrarás CPU y tardará menos en mostrarse tu página.

Comment: Okay, gracias por las recomendiaciones, ya implemento el file_exists()

Comment: Pero seria mejor ponerlo al momento de registrar las imagenes no?

Comment: También es otra opción. Si las medidas van a ser siempre las mismas puedes generarlas cuando el usuario suba la imagen. Cada método tiene sus ventanas e inconvenientes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95193/discussion-between-jesus-and-oscargarcia).